# Cloning display over multiple monitors

Tags: hardware, clone, multiple-monitors

I am developing an educational software solution where I need to clone the screen of one computer on 5 or 6 LCD screens. The screens would be 15-20 feet apart.

Is there any hardware or software that can help me do this? Each screen will just replicate the screen of the computer. I basically need to split and duplicate the video & audio signal.

I need the solution for Windows or Linux (any one) on the computer. The cloned display screens have no software - they are just LCD TVs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=multi+monitor+graphics+cards