# Find out which Display Drivers are currently running

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, driver

**Is it possible to find out which display drivers are currently running using C++ WinAPI functions?**

If it is, can you suggest what WinAPI function/s I use for this. I know that I can enable and disable the display drivers using the following functions: [DrvEnableDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) & [DrvDisableDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The reason I am doing this is because I am attempting to make my 2nd monitor toggle from *Duplicate*/Mirrored Display to *Extend* Display. In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154542/change-2nd-monitor-display-setting-to-duplicate) someone suggested that I need to disable the currently running Extend Display Driver in order to make the 2nd monitor have duplicate display. I am hoping for WinAPI functions that work on Windows 2000 and up.